# http/1.1 406 not acceptable on android app sendind data via json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, apache

I have an android app that I need to update, just to send some data via json and php to a mysql database.
Works ok with the old server, but my boss want the data to be saved in our new server, and when in the app I try to save in the new server I get this error: http/1.1 406 not acceptable 
I think, seeing the code, that the app can´t connect to the server, but I´m new con android and don´t know how to solve this...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field. Depending upon the format and the capabilities of the user agent, selection of the most appropriate choice MAY be performed automatically. However, this specification does not define any standard for such automatic selection.

via http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));  
That is the line...if I delete it, it connect with the server, if not, 406 error...

Comment: can you give the stack output please?